# Why does this program output "10"?

Tags: php

I am a newbie and tested the following code in c and in php. Please tell me why this code outputs "10".

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++);
{
    print $i;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is printing '10' ? This code should output all numbers BUT 10

Comment: remove ; on line for operator

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler  please examine thoroughly there's a semi-colon at the end of for-loop. When for loop terminates then he's printing the value (at that moment it is 10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but he is asking WHY it is printing "10". Here is the reason:

Your code is :

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++);
{
print $i;
}
?>
```

This line `for($i=0;$i<10;$i++);` is a loop, and it loops 10 times from 0 to 9. After every number the variable `$i` is incremented (`$i++`) so after first loop, `$i` has value of 1. After tenth iteration, it has value of 10.

After that you do `print $i;` so it will correctly print number 10.

But now, if you remove the semicolon after for-loop, so that the for loop has a following body

```
{
print $i;
}
```

and it will print `0123456789`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know about the termination due to semicolon, I have just the conflict in mind that if the loop runs or not. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 4):

remove `;`

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++);
                    ^
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/SeVcbl

Answer (score 4):

See Ther is a semicolon after that `for` loop. So PHP thinks that the loop has no body. So The `print $i` is executed only once

Answer (score 3):

Wrong code **;**

```
<?php
 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
 {
  print $i;
 }
```

?>

Should output all numbers

Answer (score 2):

Because of the semi-colon in your `for` statement. This ends the statement earlier than you expect and the `print` statement is no longer part of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the ;(semicolon) after the for($i=0;$i<10;$i++); statement.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon in this line and it will output 1,2,3..9:

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++);
```

If you don't do that it will first run through the loop without writing anything, and after that print $i, which has become 10 in the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon(;) next to for loop indicates that the loop contents are empty and hence the empty contents executed 10 times as in loop (`for($i=0;$i<10;$i++);`) and for each looping the value of $i gets incremented and the final value 10 gets printed as output.